# check if ip6 is down

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to check if ip6 is not connected in my code using php. My idea now is to calculate the loading if it is going to connect. I try to use this code.

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://ip6.me/');

// Trim IP based on HTML formatting
$pos = strpos( $file, '+3' ) + 3;
$ip = substr( $file, $pos, strlen( $file ) );

// Trim IP based on HTML formatting
$pos = strpos( $ip, '</' );
$ip = substr( $ip, 0, $pos );
$ipaddress = $ip;
$ip_get = explode('.',$ipaddress);
```

this work fine with me if will get ip address. But there is a time that ip6 down and it load to much. What is the best way to check if ip6 is down? I try to calculate the load of browser, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ping a server over IPv6. On linux, you can use the following code.

```
exec('ping -6 -c 1 2001:4860:4860::8888', $lines, $exit); // ping will return 0 if ping succeeds
if($exit == 0) {
    // up
    echo "up\n";
} else {
    //down
    echo "down\n";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Samuel's answer tests whether a TCP port is reachable over IPv6. In some cases, because of firewall configuration, only one of the methods may work.

Comment: I'm going to try this. thanks. I have no idea there is a code like this.

Comment: hi where did you get this code "ping -6 -c 1 2001:4860:4860::8888"

Comment: I wrote it. `-6` means to use ipv6. `-c 1` means to ping once. 2001:4860:4860::8888 is Google's dns server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native PHP method [socket_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php)

```
bool socket_connect ( resource $socket , string $address [, int $port = 0 ] )
```

> Initiate a connection to address using the socket resource socket,
>   which must be a valid socket resource created with socket_create().

```
   // Creating new socket
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
      or die("Unable to create socket\n");

    // Trying to connect, will return True on success     
    $res = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port))
```